# Testing login redirect

Tags: django, redirect, django-testing

I am trying to write a test to see if my login redirects to the correct page. At the moment I am using this code which isn't working:

```
class TestAuth(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        user_login = get_user_model().objects.create(username='admin', email='admin@test.co.uk', password='asdf1234')

        cls.user_login = user_login

    def test_login_redirect(self):
        response = self.client.post(
            reverse('udt:login'),
            {
                'username': 'admin',
                'password': 'asdf1234'
            }
        )

        self.assertRedirects(response, reverse('udt:table_list'))
```

where `udt:login` equates to `'/udt/accounts/login/'` and `udt:table_list` equates to `'/udt/table/'`.

The login functionality is Django's built-in login with a custom template. When I run the test I get the following error:

```
AssertionError: 200 != 302 : Response didn't redirect as expected: Response code was 200 (expected 302)
```

However, when I actually test the login functionality in the app I get this:

```
[2017/05/30 14:43:22] HTTP POST /udt/accounts/login/ 302 [0.13, 127.0.0.1:60127]
[2017/05/30 14:43:22] HTTP GET /udt/table/ 200 [0.15, 127.0.0.1:60127]
```

which to me seems like it is in fact redirecting correctly.

So, my question is what is wrong with my test that is causing the assertion error? I am pretty new to testing in Django so it could just be something that I am missing, but it seems like the test should be passing to me.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

The login template looks like this (just took the standard Django login template and added some bootstrap class names to it):

```
{% load bootstrap3 %}

<form id="login-form" method="post" action="{% url 'udt:login' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td><label for="id_username">Username</label></td>
            <td><input id="id_username" name="username" type="text" class="form-control"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="id_password">Password</label></td>
            <td><input id="id_password" name="password" type="password" class="form-control"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    {% if form.errors %}
        <p class=" label label-danger">
            Your username and password didn't match.
            Please try again.
        </p>
    {% endif %}
    <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" />
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
</form>
```

url for login looks like so:

```
url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'auth/login.html'}, name='login')
```

I am using Django v.1.11.1.

Comment: I can't help you with the testing but I think the best way to accomplish what you are doing is simply putting this line into your settings.py 
`LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/YourSite/'`  this works 100%.

Comment: I have that already in my settings.py and I'm still getting the same error so I'm not really sure why it's happening!

Comment: in this case I can't tell you whats wrong sorry. Lets hope some more experienced user will enlighten us.

Comment: Here's hoping! It's completely stumped me

Comment: So far you know that `self.client.post()` is returning status code 200 instead of 302. You should check `response.content` to see why.

Comment: How are you importing `TestCase`?

Comment: from django.test import Client, TestCase

Comment: And I think you are right there is something up with the way it is working as the response.content I get back after making the POST to my login url is the login form again. Not sure why that would be happening, as it doesn't do that when I log in on the app?

Comment: What does your template and url pattern look like? What version of Django are you using?

Comment: @Alasdair Please see the update above

Comment: I've spotted the problem now, it's in your `setUpTestData` method. See my answer below.

Comment: @Alasdair Yep seen and marked as correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating the user incorrectly. You should use [`create_user`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user) instead of `create()`, so that the password is correctly hashed.

```
@classmethod
def setUpTestData(cls):
    user_login = get_user_model().objects.create_user(username='admin', email='admin@test.co.uk', password='asdf1234')
```

As an aside, you can remove your `setUp` method as it is unnecessary. Django's `TestCase` class takes care of setting up `self.client` for you.

One more thing - your URL pattern is fine for Django 1.11, but you could update it to use `LoginView` to be compatible with Django 2.1+:

```
url(r'^login/$', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name= 'auth/login.html'), name='login'),
```